# Need To Convert SQL To LINQ

Tags: linq

Hi Stack i want to convert this to LINQ without any grouping in linq .
DB NorthWIND.

```
select 
SUM(UnitsInStock)UnitsInStock,
SUM(UnitsOnOrder)UnitsOnOrder,
AVG(UnitPrice) AVGUnitPrice
from Products
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
var query=from p in db.Products
        group p by 1 into g
        select new
        {
            SumUnitsInStock= g.Sum(a => a.UnitsInStock),
            SumUnitsOnOrder= g.Sum(a => a.UnitsOnOrder),
            AvgUnitPrice= g.Average(a => a.UnitPrice)
        };
```